# New to Oracle DataBase.. Need to remote access the data for small buissness

Tags: forms, oracle, oracle10g

I have developed a database for a small business but there is requirement of my client to access all the data online remotely from his laptop to keep an eye on the sales/purchases when he is away from the country or away from the Shop. On his shop i have deployed an Oracle 10g server and as front end software i have used an Oracle form 6i.

please advise me a simple newbie steps to setup this server online so my client can view the progress online and can make any desired changes remotely.

Comment: Are you trying to give access to the underlying database?  Or to the application?  Is this a web-based application?  Or a client/server application?  Are the client and the database on the same VPN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save yourself a lot of trouble and hassle, use Oracle forms 11g with Weblogic, deploy these on a server at the client's sire on the same network as the database server, and allow firewall access from outside to the web server forms app. Technically, you can set up Oracle forms 6i client to talk to a database over the internet, but I wouldn't recommend it.